# Prestashop - Loading products in cart from external website

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

We are currently investigating the possibility of pre populating the prestashop cart from an external website. There is some logic in the external website that is very difficult to implement in prestashop so we are planning to keep this logic in a wizard in an external tool and once the user selects all the products and options, he is redirected to the prestashop cart with the cart pre-popoluated with the products selected in the previous steps.

So far we have investigated the following:
- web service does not seem to provide this
- adding 1 product seems to be doable (even though there is a problem of when a user is already logged in as you need to add the token)

Any ideas how this can be done please?

Comment: did you manage to solve this?